# USing XPath to get the text inside a parent Node

Tags: xml, xpath

for example, I get the html string like this:

```
<p><br><a href=\"http://www.hello.com/en/\">www.hello.com</a></p>
```

And i want to get the result like this:

```
<br><a href=\"http://www.hello.com/en/\">www.hello.com</a>
```

But I finally get  "www.hello.com"  when using the the XPath statement

```
//p/text()
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
//p
```

It wiil select `p` element.

Comment: the result is still "www.hello.com"  with "//p" , I want the <br> and <a> node in the result string.

Comment: @MaS, It depends on how you use it in your XPath engine.

Comment: @MaS, `//p` will select any p element in the document

Comment: I don't know about the XPath engine, can you give me an example for this case?

Comment: How can I get the chars between <p> and </p>?

Comment: @MaS: `www.hello.com` are all the chars there are between `<p>` and `</p>`. `<br>` and `<a href=""http://www.hello.com/en/">` are **elements** and treated as such, they are not treated as characters.

Comment: I know both <br> and <a> are elements, but I want them in the output, how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
But I finally get "www.hello.com" when using the the XPath statement 

    //p/text()
```

This selects any *text node* that is a child of a `p` element in the document.

However, you want not only the text node children, but any children, including elements, such as `<br>` and `<a>`.

**Solution**:

Use:

```
/p/node()
```

**when this XPath expression is evaluated against the provided XML** (corrected to be made well-formed XML document):

```
<p><br/><a href="http://www.hello.com/en/">www.hello.com</a></p>
```

**the following two nodes are selected**:

```
<br/><a href="http://www.hello.com/en/">www.hello.com</a>
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

This transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select="/p/node()"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<p><br/><a href="http://www.hello.com/en/">www.hello.com</a></p>
```

**copies the selected nodes to the output**:

```
<br/><a href="http://www.hello.com/en/">www.hello.com</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/p/*
```

Will retrieve all elements that are element p children. That is what you want.

**Warning**. Your element `<br>` is not well formed. You should close it so it can be a well formed empty element `<br/>`

Comment: /p/node()   return the the same result "www.hello.com"

Comment: I don't know what XPath engine you are using. But if you do xmllint --xpath '/p/node()' file.xml - with file.xml containing your line - the ouptut is <br><a href=\"http://www.hello.com/en/\">www.hello.com</a>. I verified it before posting.

Comment: How do you run your XPath queries ?

Comment: I run it in IOS with libxml2 and library hpple